# how to sendphoto before sendmessage in nodejs

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

in telegram bot, with nodejs, i want to sendphoto and after it send message to user

i use this code:

```
bot.sendPhoto(chatId, photo);
bot.sendMessage(chatId, caption, opts);
```

but my problem is: message is shown before photo and inline buttons is shown above of photo :(
i like first photo shown and after it message with inline buttons

i use this:

```
bot.sendPhoto(chatId, photo, function(){bot.sendMessage(chatId, caption, opts)});
```

but with this code photo shown and no message shown

excuse me for bad english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use promises. You can achieve it using [q library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q).

Make sure sendPhoto function returns a promise. So that you can do the following

```
bot.sendPhoto(chatId, photo).then(function(resultFromSendPhoto){
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, caption, opts);
    //your further code goes here if you want
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
}).done();
```